# ERROR: java.lang.NullPointerException at java.io.FileInputStream

Tags: java, spring, exception

I have a problem with my code( I'm trying to fix a bug ).

This is the stack trace

```
ERROR: java.lang.NullPointerException at
java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) at
java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101) at
it.dedagroup.prosa.portal.services.DocumentiService.checkin(DocumentiService.java:604) at 
it.dedagroup.prosa.portal.controller.DocumentiController.checkin(DocumentiController.java:404) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215) at 
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
```

And this is the code where it comes out.

```
ContenutoEntita contenuto = new ContenutoAlfImpl();
contenuto.setInputStream(new FileInputStream(documentoPersonaleDTO.getPath()));
System.out.println(contenuto);
contenuto.setTipoMime(documentoPersonaleDTO.getContentType());
contenuto.setDimensione(documentoPersonaleDTO.getSize());
documento.setFirmato(documentoPersonaleDTO.isFirmato());
documento.setContenuto(contenuto);
```

can anyone help me?? thaanksss :)

Comment: Can you post the code producing this exception?

Comment: Blockquote ContenutoEntita contenuto = new ContenutoAlfImpl();

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that

```
documentoPersonaleDTO.getPath()
```

does not point to a real file. Just System.out.println that path and look if it's physically present on your disk.